# How to manipulate other app's widget in my app service? Even in lock screen state? Is it possible?

Tags: android, android-testing

I want to manipulate another app's widgets( like click button) , and even in lock screen I'd like to do that.

Is it possible?

There are two questions I doubt to achieve this goal:

The first one is  to access and manipulate other app's widgets.
The second one is to access and manipulate them in lock screen state.

Any answer will be thankful.

Comment: You can use [MonkeyRunner](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)